# Trigging an actionresult method in asp.net using a jquery dialog button asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Is there a way of making a jQuery dialog button trigger a method in controller so it works like a submit button?

Code in controller

```
[HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Create(Film filmToCreate){
            try{

                filmToCreate = new Film();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Constructed Film");
                UpdateModel(filmToCreate);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Updated Model");
                repo.Add(filmToCreate);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Added Film");
                repo.Save();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Save Databases");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Return1");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            catch {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Caught something");
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }

        }
```

// Code in dialog

```
 buttons: {
                    "Create": function() {



                    },

                    "Reset": function() {
                        $("#createForm input").attr("value", "");

                    },

                    "Close": function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }


                }
```

Is there some method in the `Url` class that will be able to link this method to this button?

Comment: at the moment it works with a normal asp.net submit button but obv I need it to work on the dialog

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) you would do something like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() 
        {
            $.get("controller/action", dataToSubmit);
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        }
    }
] });
```